# Recipe example / Example recipe

Tags: word-order

I want to add a headline to a printscreen of a recipe. The headline is supposed to say that this is one example of the recipes in the database.

> Recipe Example / Example Recipe

I don't know which one to choose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What looks natural to me is saying-

> An example of recipe

But then you want other options especially these two `recipe example` and `example recipe`.

I'd say that **both** will work. It'd be then just a matter of style. None of them can serve as an ***adjective*** so the order won't matter.

We often say `"a simple example"` but then, 'simple' is an adjective and thus, it goes first. Here, 'recipe' and 'example' both are *nouns* and therefore, it'll look okay **both ways!**

They may set an example of [a noun adjunct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct).